# ¿Cómo evitar el orden de ejecución de estos métodos? (Angular)

Tags: angular

El objetivo que quiero lograr es que los items que guardo en un Carrito sean revisados para chequear la disponibilidad que tengo de ellos en el Stock.

**¿Cómo logro esta revisión?**

Con un ciclo **for** recorro estos items y puedo obtener los ID de los productos y las cantidades que quiero de cada uno de ellos. Luego, procedo a llamar un método en el **service** para ir reduciendo el stock a medida que voy haciendo este recorrido. Por último, llamo a otro método del **service** que lo que hace es recuperar ese stock perdido.

Adjunto los dos métodos que tengo en el service:

```
stockManufacturado(id: number, cantidad: number): Observable<any> {
    try {
      return this.http.put<any>(`${this.manufacturadosUrl}/hayStockManufacturados/${id}/${cantidad}`, Boolean);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  recuperarStockManufacturado(id: number, cantidad: number): Observable<any> {
    try {
      return this.http.put<any>(`${this.manufacturadosUrl}/recuperandoStockManufacturados/${id}/${cantidad}`, Boolean);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

Adjunto el primer método:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < itemsManufacturados.length; i++) {
      let id = itemsManufacturados[i].articuloManufacturado.id;
      let cantidad = itemsManufacturados[i].cantidad;
      console.log("ID: " + id);
      console.log("Cantidad: " + cantidad);
      this.manufService.stockManufacturado(Number(id), cantidad).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("Ejecutandose metodo '1'");
       })
      }
    console.log("Ciclo terminado");
```

**Este método** me funciona tal como quiero yo, puesto que me **reduce** de manera correcta el stock. El problema es cuando lo quiero juntar con **otro método** que consiste en **recuperar** el stock que se perdió con el primero.

A continuación adjunto el segundo método:

```
console.log("Recuperando Stock Manufacturados");

for (let i = 0; i < itemsManufacturados.length; i++) {
  let id = itemsManufacturados[i].articuloManufacturado.id;
  let cantidad = itemsManufacturados[i].cantidad;
  console.log("ID: " + id);
  console.log("Cantidad: " + cantidad);
  this.manufService.recuperarStockManufacturado(Number(id), cantidad).subscribe(res => {
    console.log("Ejecutándose método '2'");
  })
}

console.log("Ciclo terminado");
```

**Si yo ejecuto estos 2 métodos me da un resultado parecido a este:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El orden que YO CREO que tendría que ser es el siguiente:

- ID de los Manufacturados
- ID: 1
- Cantidad: 2
- Ejecutando el método '1' (descuenta el stock)
- Recuperando el Stock de los manufacturados
- ID: 1
- Cantidad: 2
- Ejecutando el método '2' (recupera el stock)

Aclaro que ambos métodos probados de manera individual cumplen con lo que yo deseo, pero una vez que los junto producen este tipo de problema.

Desde ya agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda y si necesitan alguna otra porción de código me escriben y lo coloco :)

Comment: Lo que considero que pudieras realizar en tu caso es ejecutar un solo ciclo y ejecutar el stockManufacturado, una vez que te mande el evento tu observable, ejecutar el recuperarStockManufacturado, sobre el ítem que ya tiene respuesta.

Comment: Colocar esto luego de 'console.log("Ejecutándose método '2'")'  ??          this.manufService.recuperarStockManufacturado(Number(id), cantidad).subscribe(res => {
    console.log("Ejecutándose método '2'");
  })